# MSDTC fails intermittently

Tags: transactionscope, msdtc

I have a Windows 2003 server where MSDTC is running. I have set it to No Authentication Mode, with allow inbound-outbound settings. My MSDTC works but it fails for the 1st transaction of the day. On immediate another transaction it will start working.

Error is : The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or
aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D00E).

So I started MSDTC tracing, in trace file it shows this :

pid=2144;tid=2528;time=12/02/2011-10:49:39.140;seq=531;eventid=TRACING_STARTED;;"MSDTC is resuming the tracing of long -lived transactions"

pid=2144;tid=2528;time=12/02/2011-10:49:39.140;seq=532; eventid=TRANSACTION_BEGUN; tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441;"transaction got begun, description : ''"

pid=2144;tid=3288;time=12/02/2011-10:49:39.140;seq=533 ; eventid=RM_ENLISTED_IN_TRANSACTION; tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441     ;"resource manager #1002 enlisted as transaction enlistment #1. RM guid = '4e45a393-b02a-42bf-8f66-62bcb17fee8e'"

pid=2144;tid=4164;time=12/02/2011-0:49:58.390;seq=534; eventid=TRANSACTION_PROPOGATION_FAILED_CONNECTION_DOWN_FROM_REMOTE_TM ;tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441     ;"failed to propogate transaction to child node 'DBSERVER' because the connection with the remote transaction manager went down"

pid=2144;tid=4164;time=12/02/2011-10:49:58.390;seq=535; eventid=TRANSACTION_ABORTING;tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441;"transaction is aborting"

pid=2144;tid=4164;time=12/02/2011-10:49:58.390;seq=536; eventid=RM_ISSUED_ABORT;tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441     ;"abort request issued to resource manager #1002 for transaction enlistment #1"

pid=2144;tid=2528;time=12/02/2011-10:49:58.422;seq=537; eventid=RM_ACKNOWLEDGED_ABORT;tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441;"received acknowledgement of abort request from the resource manager #1002 for transaction enlistment #1"

pid=2144;tid=2528;time=12/02/2011-10:49:58.422;seq=538; eventid=TRANSACTION_ABORTED;tx_guid=4df1b0cf-26a0-43ba-8f41-965d80f92441     ;"transaction has been aborted"

pid=2144;tid=3640;time=12/02/2011-10:50:29.437;seq=539;eventid=TRACING_STOPPED;;"MSDTC is suspending the tracing of long - lived transactions due to lack of activity"

I have applied hack of Davy Brion from here, http://davybrion.com/blog/2010/03/msdtc-woes-with-nservicebus-and-nhibernate/

Also set timeout interval to 10 minutes in Transaction Options.

If the server remains idle for a while again the transaction will fail.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you looked at this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922430.  It seems **very** similar to your issue.  It looks like you have 2 servers: an app server and a DBServer?  Are the DTC settings the same on both servers?  Is there a firewall between the servers? If you do have a firewall it can sometimes help to trace the activity in the firewall.

Comment: Thanks Tuzo, My servers are in LAN and they do not have firewall, though one was in workgroup and another is in Domain. Now I have shifted both of them in Domain. Had never seen this article. I have changed the registry on the server, as per the article. I will post the status if it is fixed or not.  Thanks

Comment: Thank Tuzo. It was the same problem. You kb article helped me out. My problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the KB article that helped: [922430](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922430/error-message-when-you-try-to-start-a-transaction-in-ms-dtc-new-transaction-cannot-enlist-in-the-specified-transaction-coordinator)

If the MS DTC transaction trace log file contains this data, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
Locate the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC
Right-click MSDTC, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
Type CmMaxNumberBindRetries, and then press ENTER.
Right-click CmMaxNumberBindRetries, and then click Modify.
Click Decimal.
In the Value data box, type 60.
```

This value increases the length of time that the client computer waits for the bind packet response from the server computer. This value is double the number of seconds before the client computer stops the transaction if the client computer does not receive the bind packet response. For example, a value of 60 equals 30 seconds.

Note The value of 60 is only a recommended value. Additional testing on your configuration may be required.
Click OK.
Restart MS DTC.
Note For the slow response scenario, make sure that the ports that are required by Kerberos authentication (UDP 88 and TCP 88) are open when a firewall is involved in the Perimeter Network. The ports UDP 389 and TCP 389 (both for LDAP to find KDC) must also be open.